# postgres doesn't sort properly

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is my flask.SQLAlchemy query:

```
available_subservices = (
    ServicesForOffer.query
    .filter_by(type=u'Дополнительная')
    .order_by(ServicesForOffer.name)
    .all()
)
```

so I print it out:

```
for subs in available_subservices:
    print subs.name
```

and what I see is:

```
Доп.створка
Окно с двойными рамами (2 створки)
Окно с двойными рамами (3 створки)
окно с балконной дверью
Эркер
Мойка окон
Мойка окон, уборка кухни, уборка ванной и сан.узла
мытье холодильника
балкон
глажка
дорога
Разбор шкафа/антресоли/гардеробной
Мелкая бытовая техника
Жалюзи вертикальные
духовка
```

I don't expect anyone to know Cyrillic alphabet order, but still you can see that capitals are scattered all over, and `дорога` and `духовка` are not close to each other. Some kind of Python2 & Unicode issues probably?

P.S. when I sort by `ServicesForOffer.name.desc()` the same weird order is reproduced, inversed of course. So there's clearly something Postgres knows that I don't.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have [collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html) set properly which is responsible for how strings are sorted:

> The collation feature allows specifying the sort order and character classification behavior of data per-column, or even per-operation. This alleviates the restriction that the LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE settings of a database cannot be changed after its creation.

You may try this by simply running the query:

```
schema=> SELECT 'дорога' > 'духовка' COLLATE "en_US";
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Or executing your query manually in PostgreSQL shell with:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY name COLLATE "your collation"
```

If this works for you, you can just [altering columns collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ]
      [ USING expression ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the simmilar problem with MySQL sorting. And the solution was:

- to set `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` to schema to 'utf-8' (default was latin-1) and
- to set `DEFAULT COLLATE` to schema to 'utf8_unicode_ci'.

Another way is to create correct schema in your database.